# Qt Creator 4.3.1 not detecting MSVC 2015 compiler

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Compilers in Qt Creator are not detected (I would like to use MSVC 2015 since that's what this version of Qt Creator was built on).

I've had Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 3 installed for quite some time on a Window 7 box.

I installed Qt Creator from the downloads-open-source path...in the help menu it says "Based on Qt 5.9.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)".

I have "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.24215" installed along with several others.

What am I missing?

Comment: One more thing...I've downloaded the MSVC 2015 installer (vc_redist.x86.exe) and when I run it says I already have it installed.

Comment: Trying to install the 2015 redistributable should say that if you have Visual Studio 2015 installed. The install for 2015 will install the redistributables. This is just the redisriibutable / runtime binaries for applications created with Visual Studio 2015 it will not help you solve the qtcreator problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found out the solution...

In Visual Studio...New Project...Visual C++...Install C++...

Which will install the compilers.

This worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can't manually add MSVC to Qt Creator. If you want to use it make sure to have the correct Visual Studio version installed.

I should reinstall Visual Studio if the MSVC compiler don't appear in the Compilers tab.